# Get path from database and replace img src tag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Actually I have save file path in database from controller using asp .Net core and I am trying to get a path from data base and replace in src img tag and get file

```
            var res = await _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeFormPDF(employeeId);
            EmployeeGetFormPDF getEmployeeFormPDF = res.Data;
            
            var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("F:\\Projects\\EmployeeManagentSystemTask\\EmployeeTask\\EmployeeManagement\\employeeform.html");
            html = html.Replace("@PhotoPath", getEmployeeFormPDF.Photopath);
}
```

and add html formet

```
<html>
<body>
 <script>
        var imgpath = "@PhotoPath"
    </script>
</head>
<body> <td><img src= "imgpath" width="100" height="100"></td>
            <td><img src="" width="100" height="100"></td>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um. PDF files aren't databases... You should use an html template library like Razor rather than injecting Javascript variables via string replacement

Comment: what is the value for `getEmployeeFormPDF.Photopath` you see when you debug the code, is that a relative path? when you render the html in browser, the img src must be fully qualified web server based path and not a "disk" based file path.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I believe their method is getting PDF content from a database based on the `GetEmployeeFormPDF` method being called on `_employeeRepository`. They're not saying the PDF is the database...